# Are the Unit Ball and Any other Ball Topologically Equivalent

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

How would I correctly show that the unit ball $B(0,1)\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and the ball $B(a,r) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ are Topologically Equivalent?

I know I need to find a one-to-one function $f: X\rightarrow Y$ for which $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are both continuous to prove it is Topologically Equivalent; however, I am having a hard time finding such a function.

A function that came to mind is the equation of a circle or sphere. But I wouldn't know if that's correct.

I want to thank you for taking the time to read this question. I greatly appreciate any assistance you provide

Comment: Translate the second ball to the origin and then scale the radius.

Answer (score 2):

By proving $f:B(0,1)\rightarrow B(a,r)$ defined by $f:x\mapsto a+rx$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Yep. I didn't see the edit. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Send $\vec{x}$ to $r\vec{x}$ to stretch the unit ball into a ball of radius $r$. Then translate.  So, your function $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$ could be $f(\vec{x})=r\vec{x}+\vec{a}$.  The inverse would then be $f^{-1}(\vec{x})=\frac{1}{r}(\vec{x}-\vec{a})$.

Answer (score 1):

> A function that came to mind is the equation of a circle or sphere.

You're on the wrong track here. What you want is not a function that *defines* a ball, but rather one that *transforms* one ball (radius $1$, center at the origin) into a different one (radius $r$, center $a$).

Think about how you would do this: you would need to "inflate" (or deflate if $r < 1$) the unit ball (i.e. scale all the points by $r$) and then translate all the points from their original home near the origin to their new location near $a$. How could you write this process as a map?